# Highlight parts of an answer

Tags: feature-request

When I'm looking up an answer to a question I have in Google, and I end up here, I sometimes end up finding the same answer later on in my journey of questioning.

I would like to be able to highlight a specific part of an answer so that I can see that part right away the next time I end up on that answer.  I don't need anyone else to see that highlight.

Is that feature already available?

Comment: i though about similar functonnality but not for the same reason. In my mind, It should help OP to identfy the super important content within an answer. but as they say in the answer here, and i will quote it `it sounds like enough of a implementation nightmare`

Answer (score 5):

No, and it sounds like enough of a implementation nightmare - for what looks like very, very little benefit - that it will probably never *be* available.

This is probably best solved on the user's end.

There's browser extensions that purport to do this, for example [this one for Chrome.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/super-simple-highlighter/hhlhjgianpocpoppaiihmlpgcoehlhio?hl=en)